# Find all elements having attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all the `path` elements in the drawn SVG with an attribute `marker-end`.

I tried:

```
$('path').attr("marker-end") // Returns undefined
$('path').prop("marker-end") // Returns undefined
```

**Update**

Also `path` element `not` having the given attribute.

**Update 2**

ok, got `$('path:not([marker-end])')`

Comment: [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) ... docs [for selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) ... docs [for attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) ... docs [for filters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/) (like `:not()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
$('path[marker-end]')
$('path[marker-end=value]")
```

With other words, syntax is:

```
$("path[ATTRIBUTE_NAME]")
```